# How to reverse the order of a specific column in python

Tags: python, reverse

I have extracted some data online and I would like to reverse the first column order.
Here is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

data = []

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get("https://kworb.net/spotify/country/us_weekly.html").content, 'html.parser')


for e in soup.select('#spotifyweekly tr:has(td)'):
    data.append({
        'Frequency':e.td.text,
        'Artists':e.a.text,
        'Songs':e.a.find_next_sibling('a').text
    })
data2 = data[:100]
print(data2)
data = pd.DataFrame(data2).to_excel('Kworb_Weekly.xlsx', index = False)
```

And here is my output:

```
[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmGmI.png
```

I've used `[::-1]`, but it reversed all the columns and I just only want to reverse the first column.

Comment: Just to be clear, you're looking to reverse the values in the `'Frequency'` data field for each row?  And do you want to reverse and sort on that new value before slicing out the first 100 elements into `data2`, or do you want to flip the values only within the slice that is `data2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first column is 'Frequency', so you can get that column from the data frame, and use [::] on both sides:

```
data = pd.DataFrame(data2)
print(data)
data['Frequency'][::1] = data['Frequency'][::-1]
print(data)
```

Got this as the output:

```
   Frequency         Artists               Songs
0          1             SZA           Kill Bill
1          2  PinkPantheress  Boy's a liar Pt. 2
2          3     Miley Cyrus             Flowers
3          4   Morgan Wallen          Last Night
4          5    Lil Uzi Vert     Just Wanna Rock
..       ...             ...                 ...
95        96           Lizzo             Special
96        97   Glass Animals          Heat Waves
97        98     Frank Ocean        Pink + White
98        99    Foo Fighters            Everlong
99       100  Meghan Trainor       Made You Look

[100 rows x 3 columns]
   Frequency         Artists               Songs
0        100             SZA           Kill Bill
1         99  PinkPantheress  Boy's a liar Pt. 2
2         98     Miley Cyrus             Flowers
3         97   Morgan Wallen          Last Night
4         96    Lil Uzi Vert     Just Wanna Rock
..       ...             ...                 ...
95         5           Lizzo             Special
96         4   Glass Animals          Heat Waves
97         3     Frank Ocean        Pink + White
98         2    Foo Fighters            Everlong
99         1  Meghan Trainor       Made You Look

[100 rows x 3 columns]

Process finished with exit code 0
```